# WinAPI WriteFile

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have code

```
   HANDLE file;

   file = CreateFile(L"D:\\SystemWin\\a.txt",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    0);

    if(file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
      wprintf(L"Invalid file handle\n");
      return 1;
    }

    wcsncpy(aBuffer, L"1234567890\0", BUF_SIZE);
    WriteFile(file, aBuffer, wcslen(aBuffer), &writtenByte, NULL);
```

If I got it right in my file I shoud have text "1234567890" but I have 12345 instead. What cound be wrong? BUF_SIZE is 11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wcslen` returns the number of `wchar_t` elements in `aBuffer` before a null terminator (in your case, this is 10).

But `WriteFile` wants the number of BYTES. You need to do this instead:

```
WriteFile(file, aBuffer, wcslen(aBuffer) * sizeof(wchar_t), &writtenByte, NULL);
```

Also note that string literals are automatically null-terminated in C. So your string literal `L"1234567890\0"` is actually 12 characters long ("1234567890\0\0"). Rewrite it as just `L"1234567890"` instead.